# How to deal with multiple values of <select> in PHP?

Tags: php, multiple-select

```
<select id="industryExpect" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">item1</option>
<option value="2">item2</option>
<option value="3">item3</option>
...
</select>
```

I'm seeing something like :
industryExpect=13&industryExpect=17&industryExpect=19

Say,there are multiple value with the same KEY,

How to retrieve them from $_POST in PHP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give it a name with `[]` on the end, for example:

```
<select id="industryExpect" name="industryExpect[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">item1</option>
    <option value="2">item2</option>
    <option value="3">item3</option>
</select>
```

Then in your `$_POST` array, you'll get an array of all the selected options:

```
// assuming that item1 and item3 were selected:
print_r($_POST['industryExpect']);
/*
array
(
    0 => 1
    1 => 3
)
*/
```

Comment: Is the [] neccesary?I included it and the difference is just:industryExpect%5B%5D=6&industryExpect%5B%5D=11&industryExpect%5B%5D.And %5B%5D is [] after encoding.

Comment: So it's the standard that when there is %5B%5D in key,treat as array?

Comment: if you're using `method="GET"` (which is the default), then your values will be added to the URL and that'd be why it's getting encoded. Of course, then you'd just have to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

Starting Html file. ex. a.html

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <select name="names[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="john">john</option>
    <option value="jack">jack</option>
    </select>
    <input type=hidden name=submitted>
    <input type=submit name=submit>
</form>
```

Process.php:

```
<?php
print_r( $_POST['names'] );
?>
```