# how to get values from multiple select/listboxes in php?

Tags: php

i want to know that how to get multiple selectbox values in php
means that i have more than 1 select box on a page and it can be increased when user click on addmeans that a page can contain numerous selectboxes now plz tell me how to get the values from that boxes and also how do i get know that how many select boxes were used by user

i think an array should be used but i dont know how??

```
    <select name="select" id="select">

<option value="1">value1</option>

<option value="2">value2</option>

<option value="3">value2</option>

</select>

    <select name="select" id="select">

<option value="1">value1</option>

<option value="2">value2</option>

<option value="3">value2</option>

</select>



    <select name="select" id="select">

<option value="1">value1</option>

<option value="2">value2</option>

<option value="3">value3</option>

</select>
```

like in above example
how do i get know that how many selectboxes were used and how to get value of each box

code for adding the new dropdown

```
function addRow()
            {
                var newRow = document.all("tblGrid").insertRow();


                var oCell = newRow.insertCell();
                oCell.innerHTML = "<select name='select' id='select'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select>";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with multiple values of <select> in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452914/how-to-deal-with-multiple-values-of-select-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to use unique `id` and `name` for each select box. Otherwise it is difficult to manage them after post.

So you can do it something like this:

```
<select name="myselect[]" id="select1">

<select name="myselect[]" id="select2">

<select name="myselect[]" id="select3">
```

After form post you can get all select box values:

```
print_r( $_POST['myselect'] );
```

For number of select boxes on page you can try:

`echo count( $_POST['myselect'] );`

Comment: Can you please show your code which is adding new select boxes.

Comment: function addRow()
   {
}
    var newRow = document.all("tblGrid").insertRow();
    
    //add 3 cells (<td>) to the new row and set the innerHTML to contain text boxes
    
    var oCell = newRow.insertCell();
    oCell.innerHTML = "<select name='select' id='select'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select>";

Comment: You need to use some counter in following line to get a unique id and name: `oCell.innerHTML = "<select name='select' id='select'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select>";`

Comment: Try: `oCell.innerHTML = "<select name='select[]' class='select'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select>";`

Comment: Thanks NAVEED this works
tell me 1 more thing that how we can use php values in that javasctipt code

Comment: Please review this post for using `PHP` in `JavaScript`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10569656/149206

Comment: Also if this answer is useful, you can accept it by clicking 'tick mark' on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name attribute value in each  tag to something unique like 'select1','select2','select3' . To refer these values in PHP use $_POST['select1'] and so on. OR use $_GET['select1'] incase of get method is used in the form.

Comment: one dropdown box is shown on main page while other are created when user click on add
other dropdown were clone of the main dropdown

Comment: +1. no matter how many dropboxes you create, they'll be POSTed even they are contained within a <form> tag. As directed above, make them unique.